# How do I dynamically insert new options into dijit.form.Select

Tags: dojo

I've got a dijit select menu and I'm trying to insert new options dynamically. From inside the widget which generates the select menu I tried the following but it didn't work;

```
this.selectMenu.domNode.innerHTML = options
```

`this.selectMenu` is the attach-point and `options` is the html for the options I'd like to insert

The code above replaces the entire select menu, rather than insert the options

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dijit.byId("selectmenu").addOption({disabled:false,label:'label',selected:true,value:1});
```